# JQuery conflict with Django base .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-templates

I have a base template in Django in which i am using app.js. This app.js is used in [theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J46ZK.png).

Now i want to have modal popup by ajax and for which i need to call Jquery function. The page on which the button for popup modal is present is extending the base.html. Thus, when i try to call the page i get the following error.

**Error in console**
[image]

However, when i don't extend base.html on my page i don't get any error and am able to have the popup modal. Here the code of my page

**new.page**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
 {% load static %}
{% include "devices/_modal.html" %}


{% block content %}
  <div class="container mt-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 mb-3">

            <button class="create-book btn btn-primary" type="button" name="button">
              <span class="fa fa-plus mr-2"></span>Create book</button>
          </div>

        </div>


  </div>


{% endblock  %}

{% block extra_js %}


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"  src="{% static "user/js/jQuery-3.3.1.js"%}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"  src="{% static "user/js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"  src="{% static "user/js/jquery.bootstrap.modal.forms.min.js"%}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $(".create-book").modalForm({formURL: "{% url 'addLocation' %}"});

    });
    </script>

{% endblock extra_js %}
```

**My base.html is**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load user_tags %}
 {% load static %}

<html lang="en">
<head>

{% block extra_head %}{% endblock %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="{% static "user/images/favicon.ico"%}" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Power Management</title>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'user/css/app.css' %}">
    <style>
        .loader {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #F5F8FA;
            z-index: 9998;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .plane-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body class="light">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}

         {% block grid  %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block scripts %}

            <script src="{% static "user/js/app.js" %}"></script>
        {% endblock %}
        {% block extra_js %}

        {% endblock extra_js %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any workaround. How can i call my Jquery?

Answer (score 1):

I personally haven't used Django, but I think you could use noConflict function to avoid using the dollar sign ($) for JQuery calls.

You can use it like this:

```
JQuery.noConflict();
JQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //Code
});
```

If you want, you could use your own alias by assigning a variable to JQuery.noConflict(), like:

```
var customJQueryCall = JQuery.noConflict();
customJQueryCall(document).ready(function() {
    //Code
});
```

You may also check this in their API:

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Nope ! its not working. This time no errors but its not rendering the popup

Comment: I read a bit of Django with bootstrap for the modal creation, as shown here:

https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/

As I said, I'm not a Django person, but I guess what I could recommend you is to check in the Inspect Elements, in the Elements tab, if there exist anything with the word "modal-header" or "modal" using the search. If there is, then it may be working, just not showing in the right position. Otherwise, try running the script manually in the Console tab. Also, check if the DOM is rendering properly.